# How to remove specific duplicates that are next to each other from a string?

Tags: string, haskell, filter, duplicates

I would like to know how to remove specific duplicates from a string. An example would be:

```
"|Hello|| My|| Name|| Is|| XYZ|"
```

Should become:

```
"|Hello| My| Name| Is| XYZ|"
```

Thanks

Comment: How do you deal with "|||" ? is this "|" or "||"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A very simple and rather obvious solution would be to pattern-match on double head:

```
foo :: Char -> String -> String
foo elem (xa:xb:xs) = ...
```

Then check if `xa` is equal to `xb`, and either return them both with the rest or just one of them if they are duplicated, then move one character forward.

Comment: `foo "Hello" -> "Helo"` You also need a `Char` parameter

Comment: Ah indeed I forgot about the parameter.

Answer (score 4):

If you allow yourself `Data.List.Split` (which you should!) you can split your string into words with

```
splitOn "|" "|Hello|| My|| Name|| Is|| XYZ|"
```

which yields

```
["","Hello",""," My",""," Name",""," Is",""," XYZ",""]
```

in which you want to replace all occurrences of `""` with `"|"` and then merge the words together. This is simply a call to `concatMap`, like so:

```
concatMap (\s -> if s == "" then "|" else s) $
  splitOn "|" "|Hello|| My|| Name|| Is|| XYZ|"
```

which yields

```
"|Hello| My| Name| Is| XYZ|"
```

---

Another alternative is to split on `"||"` and join the parts together while inserting `"|"` in between. This is just

```
intercalate "|" $ splitOn "||" "|Hello|| My|| Name|| Is|| XYZ|"
```

---

Yet another alternative, and arguably the easiest to fix if it goes awry with weird edge cases is to just use regexes. It would look something like this:

```
subRegex (mkRegex "\\|\\|") "|Hello|| My|| Name|| Is|| XYZ|" "|"
```

To show what I mean by easy to fix – imagine you want to reduce any number of `|`s in sequence to just a single `|`. With the regex solution, you just have to change the regex like so:

```
> subRegex (mkRegex "\\|+") "|||Hello||||||| My|| Name|||| Is|| XYZ|||||" "|"
"|Hello| My| Name| Is| XYZ|"
```

Answer (score 1):

The key question here is what you do with more than two `|` in a row. The solutions offered here differ very much in this particular aspect.

1. Do you interpret deduplication of `||||` as "remove a | before another |", so, like all solutions based on splitOn thus far, will only rip off that `|`, turning `"Hello ||||"` into `"Hello |||"`?
2. Do you interpret deduplication of `||||` as "reduce all pairs of || into one |", so should it translate `"Hello ||||"` into `"Hello ||"`?
3. Do you interpret deduplication of `||||` as "reduce the string until only singular | occur", so should translate `"Hello ||||"` into `"Hello |"`?

So, solution for (1) has been suggested. Solutions for (2) and (3) can be built in a way similar to each other:

Solution for (2):

```
dedup c (x:y:xs) | x == c && x == y = x: dedup c xs
dedup c (x:xs) = x: dedup c xs
dedup c _ = []
```

Solution for (3):

```
dedup c (x:y:xs) | x == c && x == y = dedup c (y:xs)
dedup c (x:xs) = x: dedup c xs
dedup c _ = []
```

Just a minor tweak in when to append the `|` when a pair was found causes a big difference in behaviour.

Answer (score -2):

```
ghci> :m Data.List
ghci> let myGroupFunc = groupBy (\a b -> a == '|' && b == '|') 
ghci> map head $ myGroupFunc "|Hello|| My|| Name|| Is|| XYZ|"
"|Hello| My| Name| Is| XYZ|"
ghci>
```

`groupBy` is of type `(a -> a -> Bool) -> [a] -> [[a]]`. It takes a function and a list and returns a list of lists. `groupBy` takes the function of type `(a -> a -> Bool)` (which I will refer to as `f`) and traverses the list, passing in two elements of a time. If `f` returns `True`, then the two elements are put together in the same sublist, while if `f` returns `False`, a new sublist is created.

One way to experiment with `groupBy` is to set `f` to `(==)`:

```
ghci> groupBy (==) "aaabbbcccdeffg"
["aaa","bbb","ccc","d","e","ff","g"]
```

This groups elements together when they are *equal* or when `(==)` returns `True`, so the same letters get grouped together.

(As an aside, remember that in Haskell, a `String` is actually a `[Char]`, so an equivalent representation of `"aaabbbcccdeffg"` is: `['a','a','a','b','b','b','c','c','c','d','e','f','f',g']`

and an equivalent representation of the result is

`[['a','a','a'],['b','b','b'],['c','c','c'],['d'],['e'],['f','f'],['g']]`.)

Now lets try `groupBy (==)` on your sample input:

```
ghci> groupBy (==) "|Hello|| My|| Name|| Is|| XYZ|"
["|","H","e","ll","o","||"," ","M","y","||"," ","N","a","m","e","||"," ","I","s","||"," ","X","Y","Z","|"]
```

Notice that it groups elements together, every time of a pair of them are the same. But that's not what you want, as the above also groups `"ll"` together in `"Hello"`.

So we change the function passed to `groupBy` to only return `True` when a pair of elements are the same *and* they are the character that you want: `'|'`:

```
ghci> groupBy (\a b -> a == '|' && b == '|') "|Hello|| My|| Name|| Is|| XYZ|"
["|","H","e","l","l","o","||"," ","M","y","||"," ","N","a","m","e","||"," ","I","s","||"," ","X","Y","Z","|"]
```

Notice that it only groups the character you want together, the `'|'`. Now, since we only need one of duplicated elements, we can just take the first `Char` of each `String` and combine them to get our result:

```
ghci> map head $ groupBy (\a b -> a == '|' && b == '|') "|Hello|| My|| Name|| Is|| XYZ|"
"|Hello| My| Name| Is| XYZ|"
```

Which is the solution from the top of this answer, accept we apply `f` directly, without using a `let` expression.

Comment: Because it's just a ready solution with no explanation whatsoever and thus has little learning benefit.

Comment: Answers provide _explanations_, optionally accompanied by code examples. Code dumps are not answers.

Comment: I still disagree that a "ready solution" has no learning benefit. My original answer still had functions that you could lookup and play with in ghci. You can learn a lot from reading source code, and it is especially helpful when you can see which part of the source code does what.

Answer (score -2):

```
import Data.List.Split(splitOn)

removeDup d = concat . map rep . splitOn d
      where 
      rep s = if null s then d else s

> removeDup "|" "|Hello|| My|| Name|| Is|| XYZ|"
"|Hello| My| Name| Is| XYZ|"
```